# the php code is unable to open the python script

Tags: php, python, html

i was trying to open and read a pdf from php using python. but after executing the php code in my browser, its not redirecting to python script. 
i want my php code to execute the python script and return the output to 
php

```
php code:
<?php 
$command = escapeshellcmd("python filename.py");
$output = shell_exec($command);
echo $output;
?>
```

python code:
this code will read the pdf from the directory and extracts required data from the pdf and gives the corresponding result as an output to the php code which is printed on the browser

```
import PyPDF2
import re,time
import sys
start_time =time.time()
# open the pdf file
address="pv3.pdf"
object = PyPDF2.PdfFileReader(address)
#print('hello')
# get number of pages
NumPages = object.getNumPages()

l = list()
# extract text and do the search
for i in range(0, NumPages):
    PageObj = object.getPage(i)

    Text = PageObj.extractText()
    l.append(Text)
#print(len(l))
#print(l[0])
d={}
count=0
for i in range(len(l)):
    x = l[i].split('\n')
    for j in range(len(x)):
        if re.search('[0-9]{8}',x[j]) and (j!=len(x)-1 and re.search('-',x[j+1])==None):
            #print(x[j],'in page',i+1,',line no',j+1)
            count +=1
            str = ''
            temp =0
            for m in range(j+1,len(x)):

                if '~na' not in x[m]:
                    str+=x[m]
                else:

                    temp = 1
                    break

            if temp==0:
                #print('hello')
                y=l[i+1].split('\n')
                for n in range(len(y)):

                    if '~' in y[n]:
                        break
                    str+=y[n]
           # if d[x[j]]==None:
            d[x[j]]=str


for x,y in d.items():

    print(x,"::::",y,"...,")
    print()
            #print(l[i])
#print(d)
#print('No of matches are',count)
#print(l[0])
end_time = time.time()

#print('Total time taken :',end_time-start_time)
```

Comment: Is the py file in the directory of the file executing the script

Comment: And what happens instead when you run this code?

Comment: Yes it’s in the same directory. @jordan Robinson

Comment: @nico Haase when I run the code it should execute the python code, read the pdf and should print the pdf data. But it’s not even opening the python code at first .

Comment: It’s only for this particular python code it’s not working but for the other python codes it’s working perfectly.